# Why apt upgrade is considered unsafe on rolling release distributions?

Tags: apt

On Parrot OS, when executing `apt upgrade` a warning message will be displayed:

```
apt upgrade is unsafe on rolling release distributions.

using apt full-upgrade instead

use apt upgrade --force to override
```

Why `apt upgrade` is consided unsafe on rolling release distributions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `full-upgrade` will more readily uninstall old dependencies and install new dependencies than a regular `upgrade` would do.

This can lead to a situation where a package cannot be upgraded because it would change the installation status of too many other packages to do so.

In a rolling release distribution, it is assumed that packages are not arbitrarily held back, which allows for a lot less strict dependency information than would be technically correct.

Generating correct versioned dependencies is a lot of effort, which these distributions want to direct elsewhere, and as long as users are aware of that limitation and never perform incomplete upgrades, that can be a reasonable trade-off.

Comment: It’s not even “more readily” — `upgrade` never removes packages.